# ASP Search and Results in a single page

Tags: asp-classic

I have a single Classic ASP page that I wish to display a search form and the associated results.

When a user first comes to this page, I want to display a search form and the 10 latest properties. If a user decides to use the search form to retrieve more relevant properties, then i want the default 10 latest properties to be replaced with the users' paged search results.

So far my code looks like this;

```
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="search">
<h3>Search form</h3>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="gist188770.asp">
<label>Street: <input type="text" name="searchStreet" value="<%=Server.HtmlEncode(Request("searchStreet") & "") %>" /></label>
<label>Town: <input type="text" name="searchTown" value="<%=Server.HtmlEncode(Request("searchTown") & "") %>" /></label>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>

<%

if (Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST") then

'arrived via post get form values and do search
Dim myRecordSet
Dim myRecordSet_numRows

Set myRecordSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
myRecordSet.ActiveConnection = MM_dbconn_STRING

'collect the form input
set objDBParam = objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@ContentStreet",200,1,100)
    objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBParam
    objDBCommand.Parameters("@ContentStreet") = Request.QueryString("searchStreet")
set objDBParam = Nothing
set objDBParam = objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@ContentStreet",200,1,100)
    objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBParam
    objDBCommand.Parameters("@ContentTown") = Request.QueryString("searchTown")
set objDBParam = Nothing
set objDBParam = objDBCommand.CreateParameter("@ContentStreet",200,1,20)
    objDBCommand.Parameters.Append objDBParam
    objDBCommand.Parameters("@ContentPostcode") = Request.QueryString("searchPostcode")
set objDBParam = Nothing

'check for a match
myRecordSet.Source = "SELECT *"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "FROM ("
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "SELECT id"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "FROM ("
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "SELECT id"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "FROM VWTenantPropertiesResults"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "WHERE ContentStreet LIKE '%" & "@ContentStreet" & "%'"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "UNION ALL"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "SELECT id"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "FROM VWTenantPropertiesResults"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "WHERE ContentTown LIKE '%" & "@ContentTown" & "%'"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "UNION ALL"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "SELECT id"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "FROM VWTenantPropertiesResults"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "WHERE ContentPostCode LIKE '%" & "@ContentPostcode" & "%'"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& ") qi"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "GROUP BY"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "id"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& ") q"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "JOIN VWTenantPropertiesResults r"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "ON r.id = q.id"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "WHERE ContentBedrooms BETWEEN 1 AND 4"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "AND ContentPrice BETWEEN 50 AND 500"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "ORDER BY"
myRecordSet.Source = myRecordSet.Source& "ContentPrice"

'display the results
if myRecordSet.BOF then
response.write("Latest properties:<br>")
do until myRecordSet.EOF
%>
<div class='result'>")
  <dl><%=myRecordSet("ContentTitle")%></dl>
  <dt><%=myRecordSet("ContentStreet")%></dt>
  <dt><%=myRecordSet("ContentTown")%></dt>
  <dt><%=myRecordSet("ContentPostcode")%></dt>
</div><%
myRecordSet.MoveNext
loop
end if

else
    'arrived via get show last 10 results
    Dim myRecordSet2
    Dim myRecordSet2_numRows

    Set myRecordSet2 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    myRecordSet2.ActiveConnection = MM_dbconn_STRING
    myRecordSet2.Source = "SELECT TOP 10 FROM VWTenantPropertiesResults ORDER BY ContentPrice"

    'display the results
    if myRecordSet2.BOF then
    do until myRecordSet2.EOF
    %>
    <div class='result'>")
      <dl><%=myRecordSet2("ContentTitle")%></dl>
      <dt><%=myRecordSet2("ContentStreet")%></dt>
      <dt><%=myRecordSet2("ContentTown")%></dt>
      <dt><%=myRecordSet2("ContentPostcode")%></dt>
    </div><%
    myRecordSet2.MoveNext
    loop
end if

end if
%>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I view the page, I get the following error;

```
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'

Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

/welcome/gist188770.asp, line 98
```

Line 98 is as follows;

```
if myRecordSet2.BOF then
```

I wondered if anyone might be able to help me solve this issue? Thank you for any help offered.

Neil.

Comment: Please post relevent code into your question rather than linking to an external resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't opened the recordset at the point of you using `BOF`.

In addition you are creating a command object but not assigning the SQL text to it instead you are assigning the sql text directly to the recordset.

You sould assign the SQL to the `CommandText` property of the command object and then retrieve a recordset by calling the Command objects `Execute` method.

**Edit**:

*More stuff that needs fixing*

Your SQL concatentation doesn't include any `vbCrLf` or whitespace on the end of each line.  The SQL will not execute.

Do not assign connection string directly to `ActiveConnection`, whilst that works ADODB doesn't manage connection pooling correctly doing it that way.  Always instance a `Connection` object and assign that to the `ActiveConnection` property.

**Edit 2**:

*Yet another issue*

Your code is accessing the criteria from the `Request.QueryString` yet your `form` element specifies `method="post"` in which case you should be using `Request.Form` instead.